# Google bot cannot fetch AngularJS site in html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, hash, seo, html5mode

My site, which is using AngularJS 1.4.8 in html5 mode and NOT using hashes in URLs is not properly indexed by Google. When I fetch and render the sub-pages in google console,  it renders only the main page and apparently treats them as duplicates. It does not seem that googlebot executes Javascript although I really don't know how it can be checked on the google console. On the other hand it accepts individual URLs pointing to subpages that it can't see. Any ideas how to debug such problems?

Comment: You even haven't specified which framework version you use. You can't have angularjs and angular tags at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I see it's important. Actually it's Angular 1.4.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding `angularjs-viewhead` and generating titles for each subpage solved the problem.